# How can I set thew view property of a UITabbarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I created a new UIViewController from the wizard.

I added a UITabbarController and added view controllers for each tab.

How can I get File's Owner to set the view property correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the nib file in your interface builder

- Click on file's owner icon on the left bar (top one, looks like a yellow outlined box)
  If you don't see the right-hand sidebar, click on the third icon above "view" in your toolbar. This will show the right-hand sidebar
- In the right-hand sidebar, click on the third tab--the one that looks a bit like a newspaper
- Under "Custom Class" at the top, make sure Class is the name of the ViewController that should correspond to this view. If not, enter it
- In the right-hand sidebar, click on the last tab--the one that looks like a circle with an arrow in it
- You should see "outlets" with "view" under it. Drag the circle next to it over to the "view" icon on the left bar (bottom one, looks like a white square with a thick gray outline

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)

Comment: My custom class is referring to the correct view controller. When I go to view I can't connect it to anything :(

Comment: Do you have a view in your nib file?

Comment: I have a ViewController that is handled by a UITabBar

Comment: But does your corresponding nib file contain a view?

Comment: Yes it contains a UITableViewController whose view outlet is connected

Comment: so how do you add the controllers to the uittabbar?

Comment: each tab contains a viewcontroller