# Adding a .xib file to a UIViewController subclass?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

I have made a UIViewController subclass without a .xib file, thinking I would not need it. Now I realize that it would be very useful, but I am unsure of how to add a .xib file to it. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a .xib file, then go into interface builder, and then into the 'Identity Inspector' panel; there you will find a field called "class" under Custom Class header, select the class that you want to be added to your .xib file from the dropdown. (Make sure you select the File's Owner in the little sidebar of the xib display area).

Comment: how do I make a .xib file by its self?

Comment: Press 'command+n', there will open a panel for creating new files, in the left column, under 'iOS' choose 'User interface' and then 'View'. There you go.

Comment: Also make sure you set the **view** outlet.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder