# loading a xib file

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

Hello I am just a beginner.

I have created a new xib file. Now I am trying to call it like the code below but it does not work.

This is what I have done in file's owner:

[image]

```
UIViewController *controller;
controller = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserFeedback" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "UserFeedback" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Comment: Don't use use UIViewController just make a subclass of UIViewController and use that subclass. And also the xib must be mapped with that subclass.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder

Comment: I have doubt it whether it is set to the appropriate class AFMoviePlayerController or not.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you have created "controller.h" and "controller.m" UIViewController.

Then give the class "controller" into "UserFeedback" .xib file.

And bind the view object with "UserFeedback" .xib file.

Try with this and let me know.

Almost you will get success.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the technique you can use:

UIViewController *controller;
controller = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserFeedback" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

the above code is correct but first u have check controller view is binding or not ..i think error is say  that your not binding controller view

Answer (score 0):

Following diagram will help you understand

[image].

As I can see from your code Now

```
 ATMoviePlayerController *controller;
 controller = [[ATMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserFeedback" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

Comment: I have mapped view with file's owner, now I don't get an error but the problem is nothing happens...

Comment: So please map it click on fileowner than on the right hand side panel click on 3rd tab and in custom class mention ur class

Comment: I did it now, but nothing happens.

Comment: Right click on File owner and select Map view to view too

Comment: Actually my issue was something else, in my code I was also closing the actual view, turns out it was closing the loaded xib as well...

Answer (score 0):

Seems the outlet is set correctly in the storyboard but while accessing it in the code you might have to ammend some code.

```
AFMoviePlayerController *controller = [[AFMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UserFeedback" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```