# iPad integration

Tags: xcode, ipad, user-interface

I've started a project using only iPhone as its default device, but now I want to use this project in iPad version also.

I've taken a iPad .xib UIView and all the coding used in didFinishLaunching: method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControlleriPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But as I run the project an error occurs showing this message

2013-03-29 11:59:06.339 animation[800:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewControlleriPad" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x159b012 0x12a8e7e 0x159adeb 0x2cd8c8 0x2cddc8 0x2cdff8 0x2ce232 0x21d3d5 0x21d76f 0x21d905 0x226917 0x21eb 0x1ea157 0x1ea747 0x1eb94b 0x1fccb5 0x1fdbeb 0x1ef698 0x25fddf9 0x25fdad0 0x1510bf5 0x1510962 0x1541bb6 0x1540f44 0x1540e1b 0x1eb17a 0x1ecffc 0x1e2d 0x1d55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Does anybody knows what is this error??? How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance :-)

EDITED:

Here's my problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8xzoj7v7wx04iv/pb.mov

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder

Comment: Thanks Sunny and Bauch

Comment: connect iboutlet and give the name of the class to xib.

Comment: Sorry... But still this didn't work for me..... :(

Comment: Still you are getting same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error `'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewControlleriPad" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`
 go to your xib(nib) right click your view and connect to File owner as shown in figure.This solve your problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've done that already, but as i right click on the view and drag the reference to the file owner's, it just doesn't let me to do that... 
Here's the problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8xzoj7v7wx04iv/pb.mov

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but I just created a new project. Setting Devices to "Universal" at the time of creating the project.... and copy-pasted the whole thing from my last project..... ;)