# replace a .xib file with another one

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to replace .xib files of an iPad app with iPhone version,so I created a xib file and lined all the IBOutlet objects, then I set file's owner, but it still went like this:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "LoginVC" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

so have I missed something?where the problems may lie?thanks for any kind advice.

Comment: how did you do the replacing? did you just take the original iPhone XIB files and put new iPad-sized XIB files to make an iPad-only app? or what else did you do?

Comment: here: 1.delete original iPad xib. 2.create an iPone xib. 3.create all the objects that iPad xib has in iPhone xib. 4.line the objects with the objects in .h file.5.set the file owner as the name of the view controller which was once the controller of iPad view xib.Anything missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this post: [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)

You forgot to do this step: `You should see "outlets" with "view" under it. Drag the circle next to it over to the "view" icon on the left bar (bottom one, looks like a white square with a thick gray outline`

Hope this helps you...