# Two nib files connect with .h and .m?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I developed an app in iphone now i need to also create this same app on ipad, I have the following files

```
LoginViewController.h
LoginViewController.m
LoginViewController.xib

now i added new file for ipad:

LoginViewController~ipad.xib
```

now i am getting an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "LoginViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787664/load-another-view-to-exist-tab-on-uitabbarcontroller/16787787#16787787

Comment: `LoginViewController~ipad.xib`->`view` needs to be set to `File Owner's`->`view` property in the Interface builder.

Comment: this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder explains everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some step to go:-

- create New Xib for Ipad like you say `LoginViewController~ipad.xib` and open it.
- click on file Owner--> and like bellow:-

[image]

now your ipad xib is also with your Loginviewcontroller customeClass

- now you just need to check it IsIphone or Ipad like:-

`#import "Homeviewcontroller.h"`

`#import "LoginViewController.h"`

`#define isIpad (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` //define here above **implementation** method

`@implementation Homeviewcontroller`

now if you want newNib load after crating as par above image you can load like bellow:-

```
if(isIpad)
{
   LoginViewController *ObjLoginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
   LoginViewController *ObjLoginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

**EDIT**

Connect your FileOwner to main view like:-

[image]

Comment: Nitin you provide me the code of condition, where it will define? in .m?

Comment: Nitin in which file i put your code, i am not using "Homeviewcontroller.h", basically i am new with xcode.

Comment: Where you put you loginviewcontroller ?

Comment: i mean in .h or .m file or other place?

Comment: where you want to push your loginviewcontroller there you put code for example at button click event you want to loginviewcontroller then in .m file button click-event u should put code as i mention in answer

Comment: Nithin one more thing, I think issue is resolved but there is another issue,Unknown class LogonViewContrller in Interface Builder file.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "LoginViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

how i can set outlet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30821/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-adnan-khan)