# creating a UIWebView dynamically on a UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I need to fill UIViewController with UIWebView dynamically. I am using the UIWebviewController to load automatically on iPhone and iPad. I am using a UINavigationController to push the UIViewController on to the screen.

Here is what I had done

in the view controller code ( in *.h )

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
```

( in *.m file )

```
@synthesize webview;
```

( in viewDidLoaded method )

```
self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.webview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.webview];
```

I am pushing the viewcontroller like this

```
CommonViewController *commonController = [CommonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:commonController animated:YES];
```

I am getting exception

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "CommonViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.' ***

can anyone tell me what is causing the exception. I have added the webview to view, I am not sure what to do next !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this post: [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)

You forgot to do this step: `You should see "outlets" with "view" under it. Drag the circle next to it over to the "view" icon on the left bar (bottom one, looks like a white square with a thick gray outline`

Hope this helps you...