# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key topViewControllerStoryboardId

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm trying to rebuild the Basic Example and whenever I start my application I end up with following error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x16d838b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key topViewControllerStoryboardId.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I just don't know where to keep looking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder

Comment: Try searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key+

Comment: I have got same error. Its working in iOS 8 iPhone 6, but not in iOS 7 iPhone 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are trying to rebuild an application, there must be some links/connections left with your nib/xib/storyboard file.Right now i dont have MAC, but in your storyboard file, check relation inspector (Last option where attribute & identity inspectors are there). There must be some relations left. Check it & let me know if its not working

Comment: I added the attributes to the view instead of the controler, so it was my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was my bad. I accidentally selected the View within the Sliding Controller and added runtimes to the view instead of the controller...