# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: ...' with name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to add a custom cell to a tableView

i've first created a xib file with 2 label "name" & "description" i've linked it to a controller  "customCellAchievementController"

it seems that the nib isn't found when i try to create the tableView

any idea where this can fail ?

i've redefine the class of my xib to the controller, i've change the identifier to the one i'm using in the code, i've check if the xib file is in the build phases / copy bundle resources and everything seems good i really don't understand ...

there is my code

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [achievement count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomCellAchievementController *cell = (CustomCellAchievementController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil){

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.name.text= [achievement objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.description.text = [description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your nib file?

Comment: did you rename your xib outside xcode?

Comment: you can even check if the nib file is added in the bundle under "Copy bundle resources" section of the "Build phases" tab for the Xcode target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCellAchievementController *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: customCellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *arr1=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellAchievementController" owner:nil options:nil ];
    for(UIView *vie in arr1)
    {
        if([vie isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell=(CustomCellAchievementController*)vie;
            cell.name.text= [achievement objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.description.text = [description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
    }
}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: try this if u need modification i change something

Answer (score 0):

Check your outlets. Outlests should associate with class not with class owner.
 For detail refer [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder).