# Cannot create new outlets in interface builder, old ones have a warning symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, builder

I am not sure what is causing this problem, but I now cannot create outlets. When I create an outlet it appears and works fine in code, but does not appear under the view controller in storyboard. Old outlets have a warning symbol on them like this[image]

When I remove this outlet, its gone and does not appear back to connect. I am running Xcode beta 6.2 because moving to 6.2 temporarily fixed this problem because I was having it beforehand in 6.1.

Here is the .h file of this class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DashboardViewController : UITableViewController {
   NSString *currentDay;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *dayLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *blockLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *currentClassLabel;

@end
```

and here are the outlets listed in storyboard [image]

[image]These are the details of the warning, but this is .h file's code for this class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController {
  IBOutlet UIScrollView *AISScrollView;
  IBOutlet MKMapView *AISMapView;
}
 -(IBAction)studentHandbook:(id)sender;
 @end
```

Comment: r u deleted the button action in anywhere in your view controller

Comment: can you add the .h of the view controller?

Comment: check in interface builder the view is connected or not? if view is not connected means shows like that only.

Comment: looks fine.. what does the warning say?

Comment: 1) restart xcode, 2nd) check if class file is same for viewcontroller on storyboard.

Comment: @GalMarom Updated the bottom of the question.

Comment: @sheshnath Restarted xcode multiple times, cleaned project, deleted derived data. View Controller in storyboard is the same as it is in code. The one weird thing is that when I type in class names, it does not autocomplete. I think this MAY have something to do with the Module as no module is set for the view controller. When I try to set a module no modules are available to select.

Comment: you using storyboard or xib(Interface Builder)?

Comment: @Arunakumari storyboard

Comment: "I type in class names, it does not autocomplete" this is the issue, do you have xcode5, if yes try to bind class names with this.

Comment: @sheshnath I'm running Xcode 6.1 and 6.2

Comment: have you properly set class file in viewcontroller on storyboard(show identiy Inspector -> CustomClass -> class) check class name for viewcontroller in storyboard

Comment: @Arunakumari Yep, the class connected to the View Controller in storyboard is the same class that the outlets are in.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? 
Have you tried it out?

Comment: @GalMarom Yes, See my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, I ended up finding a solution and that was moving the project out of the directory that it was in. It was in my Dropbox folder and moving it out fixed. If anyone has this problem in the future and also happens to have the proj in their Dropbox, move it out.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before, seems so obvious now. Thanks man! Moral of the story don't use Dropbox :)

Comment: @JoeBarbour I love and use Dropbox every day. Just don't use it for an Xcode Project.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController {
  IBOutlet UIScrollView *AISScrollView;
  IBOutlet MKMapView *AISMapView;
}
 -(IBAction)studentHandbook:(id)sender;
 @end
```

to that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *AISScrollView;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *AISMapView;

 -(IBAction)studentHandbook:(id)sender;

 @end
```

Comment: Changing the code to this does not do anything. When I remove the outlet that has the warning, the outlet just disappears and is not available to reconnect.

Comment: I would suggest you to split the view - one side put the .h and in 1 side the xib. 
Ctrl+drag the UIViews (MKMapView and UIScrollView) from the storyboard to the .h and choose touchUpInside: or whatever you need.
What is the output?

Comment: When I try to control+drag the outlet from the .h file into the views with the Xcode split view enabled, it just won't highlight the views when I hover over them. Nothing happens when I release.

Comment: try to do it the other way around - storyboard to .h - it should linked it automatically. but before discard the outlets at the .h and erase the connector at the storyboard. do clean just for case.

Comment: So this created the outlet again, but the outlet appears with the warning symbol when created. The outlet says that no outlet with that name exists which is obviously not true because that outlet was setup by CTRL+Dragging.

Comment: Weird... it's obviously a bug. 
Try to restart the computer, clean the project...

Comment: Restarting the computer is unlikely to have an effect here. I'd suggest cleaning the build folder (Cmd-Opt-Shift-K) to clear the index. If this doesn't work, please file a Radar at bugreport.apple.com and include a sample project that reproduces so we can investigate. Do the connections work at runtime? Any console warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone suffers from the same thing again, the best answer inside this other thread did the trick for me:

[XCode 6: can't connect any IBOutlet to ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203970/xcode-6-cant-connect-any-iboutlet-to-viewcontroller)

Removing the .h and .m files from the project (their references) and readding them again was the solution that worked for me.