# Using IBActions in a Storyboard, unnamed outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Can't explain other than in this screenshot.

[image: problem]

I know what your problably going to say first, "you made those connections and then deleted the IBOutlets in the class file." Nope, I even double check by going to the *Identity Inspector* and click on the *Go to Class* button in the text field class of this *UIViewController*. The connections are there and the application runs without the `..this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <outlet name>` error.

[image: code outlets]

This is an issue to me because any new outlets do not show up, other than having my workspace split into two views and doing the connection from the interface to my code directly. Same result but I don't want to find out that this has been creating a bigger problem than just me being lazy

I've also noticed when I filled in the class names in the *Identity Inspector*, nothing is shown or auto filled like normally. I've checked to see if the files are imported and they have.

I looked back and noticed these classes were added to the project vs renaming the template files when creating a new project

More Stuff :)

[image: Identity Inspector]

Comment: Have you tried common fixes like cleaning, restarting etc.?

Comment: Sadly i was too lazy to try restarting myself, but i just cleaned, closed and reopened the storyboard file, restarted Xcode, nothing :(

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/26804960/1271826

Comment: That appeared to have helped, thank you for the link!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203970/xcode-6-cant-connect-any-iboutlet-to-viewcontroller/26804960#26804960)

Solved by just removing the references and adding back to the project and the connections appeared normally. without the ! errors

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that there isn't any extra/irrelevant User Defined Runtime attributes.

Comment: blank as i checked and bc idk how to use those :3

Comment: it lies under attributes inspector

Comment: I found them under the *Identity Inspector* of the *UIViewController*. am i not suppose to have the view controller selected? Because I still see that there is no entered values

Comment: no, AFAIK, you have to check each control's runtime attributes by selecting each control one by one and hav to remove the wrong entry

Comment: Okay then, there's nothing in any of the controls in this file, i checked, jus now

Comment: Did you copy this UIViewController from anyother project? Please also double check that its inherited from UIViewController class in .h file (if objective c) and in .swift (if swift). one more thing to confirm is the class you assigned to UIViewController in IB is correct or not. if possible please provide error log. thnx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85331/discussion-between-user1967709-and-zaz).

Answer (score 0):

Check the base class (and the "module") of the view controller to make sure it is also specified. If it can't find the base class, it won't find the outlets either.

[image]

Also, if you hover over the `!`, it will show you an error message. If it says something like "UIViewController does not have an outlet called labelXPeak", then that means that there's a problem with the base class. See what class name that pop up error message reports and that will help diagnose the problem.

[image]

Comment: That is what i see when hover over the error, but when i look at the base class i see this http://i.stack.imgur.com/zpzPi.png D: all names and titles match up, nothing was connected and then removed with the connections left behind

Comment: isn't that illustrated in the questions image? what you're asking me to show you. and the errors does show "MonitoringViewController does not have.." but in the image in the edit show, the outlets are there

Comment: interesting.. how would i fix this? would this be the answer? because i'm looking at my other projects and they all say None but do not have this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85334/discussion-between-user1967709-and-rob).