# Swift Button connection fail

Tags: ios

After I deleted the old connection, and reconnected, the Xcode hints is still the same.

[image]

Project: https://github.com/zetaosun/IOS/tree/master/PitchPerfect

Comment: share code snippet and explanation instead of whole project.

Comment: what do you mean?  What's going wrong?

Comment: Try the solution given by @JJBoursier, It worked in my machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931865/error-in-xcode-6-view-controller-does-not-have-an-outlet-named-subview

Comment: @Imad Thanks,the question is resolve.

Comment: @zetao Happy coding :-)