# CustomView Does not show up in StatusBar

Tags: macos, swift, nsview, nsviewcontroller, nsapplication

I am trying to make a `SystemStatusBar` popover for Mac. (Roughly, translating [this](https://github.com/maxim-pervushin/NSPopover-From-Status-Bar-Item/tree/master/StatusItemPopup) Cocoa app to a Swift app). However, the view that I am using never shows up and the popup appears in the bottom left of the screen replicating the `StatusBarItem`.

This is what I expect (and that happens in the example from case of example from the link):
[image]

and this is what actually shows up (in my, Swift version of the application) instead of the `NSPopover` being shown in the StatusBar [Showing or Hiding the popup is controlled by the two buttons as shown in the previous figure. In this screenshot I have not added that window as it remains the same.]:

[image]

This is the **AppDelegate**:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    var statusView : StatusView!
    var popController: PopViewController!


    @IBAction func showPop(sender: NSButton)
    {
        statusView.showPopup()
    }

    @IBAction func hidePop(sender: NSButton)
    {
        statusView.hidePopup()
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
    {
        var height = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().thickness
        statusView = StatusView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, CGFloat(height), CGFloat(height)))
    }
}
```

The **CustomView**:

```
class StatusView : NSView, NSMenuDelegate
{
    var imageView: NSImageView!
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem!

    var popover: NSPopover!
    var popController: PopViewController!

    required init? (coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect)
    {
        var height = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().thickness
        imageView = NSImageView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, CGFloat(height), CGFloat(height)))
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(CGFloat(height))

        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        imageView.image = NSImage(named: "mf-image-black.png")
        self.addSubview(imageView)
        statusItem.view = self

        popover = NSPopover()
        popController = PopViewController(nibName: "PopViewController", bundle: nil)
        popController.view = self
        popover.contentViewController = popController

    }

    func showPopup()
    {
        if(!popover.shown)
        {
            popover.showRelativeToRect(self.frame, ofView: self, preferredEdge: NSMinYEdge)
        }
    }

    func hidePopup()
    {
        if(popover.shown)
        {
            popover.close()
        }
    }
}
```

and the **ViewController**:

```
class PopViewController: NSViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var statusView: StatusView!

    override init?(nibName: String?, bundle: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

I am not exactly sure what is that I am missing here. The StatusItem never seems to make use of the `PopViewController` nib.

Comment: I had been struggling with this for so many days. Ultimately, the last point of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395750/174184) that fixed the problem. I guess there's so much that I need to learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)