# Programmatically segue from MainViewController to .xib view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm having trouble finding help on performing a segue, or some kind of view transition with swift with at least iOS 8 or later. I'm trying to avoid using the Storyboard editor as much as possible, aside from implementing a segue from the Main View Controller to the xib.

This is what I have so far:

```
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let secondViewController = ViewController(nibName: "SwitchRegionSegue", bundle: nil)
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code above is called from the main ViewController.swift using the Single View Application new project scaffold. But it results in a crash:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SwitchRegionSegue" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

I also have these two files like so:

`SwitchRegionSegue.xib`

`SwitchRegionSegue.swift`

I've made sure that the file's owner custom class for the xib is set to `SwitchRegionSegue : UIView`

My SwitchRegionSegue.swift is just a blank canvas and looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class SwitchRegionSegue: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    var nibName = "SwitchRegionSegue"

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

}
```

Anyone know what it is that I'm not doing correctly here? (suggestion to a good swift & xib textbook would be awesome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues that I noticed from you code:

1) Inherit **SwitchRegionSegue** from **UIViewController** instead of **UIView**

2) Set the Class of your xib

3) Connect the view object in the nib to **view** outlet

Then write this code in your main ViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let secondViewController = SwitchRegionSegue(nibName: "SwitchRegionSegue", bundle: nil)
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the *.xib* file, two things must be true:

- The File's Owner proxy's class is set, in the Identity inspector, to the class of the view controller.
- The `view` outlet of the File's Owner proxy must be connected to the view object in the nib.

You have forgotten one of both of those.

Comment: And since you ask for a textbook: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_in_a_separate_nib (the current edition is in Swift, but the facts have not changed, so this will do)

Comment: My File's Owner does not have a view outlet, I know exactly what you are talking about from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder    However, my file's owner doesn't have the view outlet in 'SwitchRegionSegue'. How do I give my xib File's Owner the view outlet? I've already declared a UIView property named 'view' in SwitchRegionSegue.swift.

Comment: The `view` outlet will appear only when you have done the _first_ step, giving the File's Owner the proper view controller class.