# Load View Controller from storyboard with a particular size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know if it is possible to load/present modally a UIViewController with a "free form" size like the image below

[image]

I want to load the red one allways on top (allways visible) and interact with the ViewController below (blue one) at the same time.

EDIT: what i want is to show and hide FROM APP DELEGATE a small view controller to controll the music in my app.
I was trying with a xib file with a custom UIViewController as the file owner (see image below). The xib is being showed right the way i want, but the UIViewController associated to it, id doesn't load and i don't know why...

[image]

So i thought to do it with a UIViewController free formed but im not making it and i don't know wich is the best way

EDIT2:

With the xib file way i did the next:

In AppDelegate i have a function showPlayer that is called with local notification to show the xib

```
-(void)showPlayer:(int)tag andObjetoCancion:(NSArray *)objetoCancion
{

ZocaloPlayerViewController *vc = [[ZocaloPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ZocaloPlayerView" bundle:nil];
[vc setObjectoCancion:[objetoCancion mutableCopy]];

if (globals.isPlaying) {
    [vc setCambiar:YES];
}else{
    [vc setCambiar:NO];
}

//here playerView is a UIView initiated in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
if (playerView == nil) {
    playerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  self.window.frame.size.height, self.window.frame.size.width, altoPlayer)];
}

//keyWindow is UIWindow
//NSLog(@"Abro view %ld", (long)viewPlayer.tag);
keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview:playerView];
[keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:playerView];


NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ZocaloPlayerView" owner:vc options:nil];
mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  //This part hung me up


[playerView addSubview:mainView];

//needed to make smaller for iPhone 4 dev here, so >=200 instead of 748
[playerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[mainView]-0-|"
                           options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                           metrics:nil
                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mainView)]];

[playerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[mainView]-0-|"
                           options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                           metrics:nil
                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mainView)]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    playerView.center = CGPointMake(self.window.frame.size.width / 2, self.window.frame.size.height - mitadAltoPlayer);
    [self.window layoutIfNeeded];
}];

}
```

ZocaloPlayerViewController *vc is being instantiated but the viewDidLoad function inside it is not being called.... That is my first problem...

With the UIViewController free formed way i don't know how to do it...

Comment: so you are saying the red should be displayed as navigation bar ?

Comment: Teja Nandamuri. No, i want to show it from the bottom of the window. Let say, like a bottom bar...

Comment: yes you can access any view controller view and display it in a another view. Or Try using container view.

Comment: Teja, look i edited the question explaining better the problem

Comment: show the code related to how you tried to put the red view in your current controller view .

Comment: you need to access vc.view to get view did load on Zocalo get called.

Comment: can you modify the code above? because i tried to do [keyWindow addSubview:vc.view]; and [keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:vc.view]; but nothing shows...

Comment: you should not add subview to the window, instead add the subview to the root vi.ew controller

Comment: but i want to make this xib allways open and showed. it is posible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem with this post [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)
(i was missing the UIView outlet)

and i changed my code in the showPlayer function to this:

```
-(void)mostrarPlayer:(int)tag andObjetoCancion:(NSArray *)objetoCancion
{

ZocaloPlayerViewController *vc = [[ZocaloPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ZocaloPlayerView" bundle:nil];
[vc setObjectoCancion:[objetoCancion mutableCopy]];

if (globals.isPlaying) {
    [vc setCambiar:YES];
}else{
    [vc setCambiar:NO];
}


if (playerView == nil) {
    playerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  self.window.frame.size.height, self.window.frame.size.width, altoPlayer)];
}

//NSLog(@"Abro view %ld", (long)viewPlayer.tag);
keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview:playerView];
[keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:playerView];

[playerView addSubview:vc.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    playerView.center = CGPointMake(self.window.frame.size.width / 2, self.window.frame.size.height - mitadAltoPlayer);
    [self.window layoutIfNeeded];
}];

}
```