# Loaded the ... nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

[image]

Here's my select outlets bar:

[image]

How can I solve this?

I've tried the solutions suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set), but none have worked for me so far.

Comment: Click on "View" and goto connection and see if the view has connection or not. If not, then connect it to File Owner.

Comment: @GeneCode it does have a view connection to File's Owner. do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this was closed as a duplicate; I've tried what was suggested in the other question, but none of those solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have changed the content of you view. And because of that the nib has lost its view element.
To fix this error open your nib and select the `File’s Owner`. In the right-hand sidebar, click on the last tab--the one that looks like a circle with an arrow in it. See what you have connected to your controls in the storyboard. Make sure the view has connected to the `view` on the left bar. You can find more answers close to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder). You can post some images of your `select outlets` bar if the error still exists.

Comment: I don't have any nibs in my project because I'm using storyboards. What should I open instead of my nib? My view?

Comment: I've updated my question with a picture of my select outlets bar.

Comment: It looks something wrong with the connection called "big view". try to delete it and reset the connection to the view. Besides which I said is the last connection.

Comment: It's no need to set the root view of the ViewController to "big view". you can just use it as "self.view" in the VC.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the Big View connection, but what do you mean by using self.view in the VC?

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you run the project after you removing the connection called "bigView"?  From your image I also see the connection with the gray color. Try to remove the last one.

Comment: I'm not sure how to remove that. The x button doesn't work for that one because it's faded.

Comment: Remove the last one in your above image.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: That didn't work. Here is an updated screenshot of what my select outlets bar looks like: http://imgur.com/a/ZdqYW

Comment: The basic view has two connections. Try to remove one, and run the project.

Comment: I simply had to rename the subview to something different and follow what you told me in the previous comment and the problem resolved itself.

Comment: Have a happy day :)